# Django Admin how to add filter menu like basic UserModel:

Tags: python, django

This is how looks template of Django Admin Model:

**[image: strong text]**

This is model which I created:

```
class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.URLField()
    is_qualified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I create same filter menu ? for `is_qualified` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify this in the [**`list_filter`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) of the `ModelAdmin` you make for your model:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import ProfileUser

class ProfileUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('is_qualified',)

admin.site.register(ProfileUser, ProfileUserAdmin)
```

It is however advisable only to use this for fields with a limited number of options (a `BooleanField` of course is a good candidate for this).

Comment: Simple as f..., there is syntax error `list_filter = ('is_qualified ',)` it would be the problem if someone copy paste in future : ) Thank you!

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm: at first sight there is no syntax error, this is a singleton tuple, You however made a typo: you added a trailing space to `'is_qualified '` which will likely raise an error.